# Search function working fine in localhost but not in VPS

Tags: php, laravel, search, vps

I have this search function in my laravel website, its working fine in my localhost. But when I deployed it in [vultr vps](https://www.vultr.com/) using git hook, the search function is not working properly.

When i click the search button in localhost, it will produce a url of like this: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/search?query=test&location=&keywords=&_token=I5BDCrqHtdwvsSwrHTrdAAGYfdukPCgU3OAGDySw`

but when in the deploy server nothing happens, it just do some postback load.

**SearchController.php**

```
public function getSearch(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'query' => 'required_without_all:keywords,location',
        ], ['query.required_without_all' => 'Please fill atleast one field.']

    );

    $query = $request['query'];
    $location = $request['location'];
    $keywords = $request['keywords'];

    if (isset($location) && isset($query) && $keywords) {
        $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->where('title', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')->where('location', 'like', $location)->where('body', 'like', $keywords)->paginate(5);
    }
    .......
    else {
        $query = '';
        $location = '';
        $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->where('location', 'like', $location)->paginate(5);
    }

    return view('includes.search-index', ['posts' => $posts]);      
}
```

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('/search', [
    'uses' => 'SearchController@getSearch',
    'as' => 'search'
]);
```

**search.blade.php**

```
<form action="{{ route('search') }}" method="get" >
    .....
</form>
```

Any idea? It seems that the request is not passing? Because I got an empty request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an error in my `nginx` `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file.

```
location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?query_string;
}
```

and it should be

```
location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check what link is created in form action. If you have localhost in your .env or config possible that route create incorrect link. Otherwise look at your server logs.

You can debug also in your controller. As first does it run, in next steps where the problem is.

Comment: `search?query=test&location=&keywords=&_token=4RYLKod1wTRxlblKKpRzKa6Z4YQrAzELjJNP66ti` i try to debug and return the `query` value but its turns out a blank page. The return must be `test`.